# Software for drawing graph algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, drawing

I'd like some tips on software (Windows or Linux) to draw graphs for teaching algorithms. Ideally, it should have support for several frames of similar drawings with little variation between them and, most importantly, changes could be propagated to all frames.

I currently use yEd to draw graphs, but copy/paste between different images has several issues, for instance, if I change the color of a node after having created several copies, I have to change it in each image separately.

I once used (for a very brief time) Macromedia Flash and I believe it would be quite nice to try with it, but it costs simply too much and is overkill.

DOT is quite nice but I couldn't find a graphical interface with quick feedback to ease the task. It wouldn't bother me if the tool required some programming, but the text-to-image conversion should be almost real-time.

Last time I tried Dia and Visio both didn't seem to have what I want, but maybe I missed it...

Thanks!

Comment: [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

Comment: i would suggest you to use graphviz... you just need a weekend to fully understand how to type/edit the text file and the software makes the GIF/PNG/JPEG for you, it even provides you with the html map to include this on a web page if needed some interaction in the nodes.

Comment: imho graphviz is a bad suggestion - it will reshape on each node which is what is expressly not required.

Comment: I tried graphviz before but I didn't master it enough for it to help me draw faster than by using yEd or Dia. I thought a bit about it, and I believe what I would like would be: some CSS-like definition for visual properties (i.e., shape, size, color, etc) and some interactive manipulation when it comes to position, alignment, labels, and overall visualization. Automatic layout can be useful sometimes, but when I want to have precise control over the positioning, I find graphviz doesn't help me much. And yEd is very good at aligning, selecting and placing nodes, but has no CSS-like properties.

Comment: Actually, to be fair to yEd, I think its "import" feature may help, though I have to check it. If it were open-source it would be perfect; I'll see what I can do for now, thank you everyone for your tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/features/) for Mac/iPad has the notion of "shared layers" which might be what you are looking for. From the official website:

```
Share the love between your canvases with shared layers. 
When you have common elements that you'd like to display 
on different canvases, shared layers make it easy to keep 
them updated. Change any object on a shared layer (a logo, 
a background, a wireframe) and the change instantly shows 
up on every canvas that shares the layer.
```

However it's not multi-platform.

Comment: Indeed, this is the feature I want, but $199 for the professional version + a Mac are way out of my budget. Though I wanted it to be compatible with Windows/Linux, your answer is the closest one to what I sought.

Answer (score 0):

[Gephi](http://gephi.org/features/) and [Ubigraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/index.html) support dynamic graph visualization, and both run on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a bit Gephi but I don't believe it's quite what I was expecting. So far I fail to see how it could help in my specific task. But I'll try it later, along with Ubigraph, and see if they are useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider this: http://code.enthought.com/ It is python and well documented.

Comment: Thanks, I installed it and looked a bit, and though it seems more related to scientific visualization, I believe it can also be used for what I had in mind. Moreover, when googling for some screenshots, I happened to stumble upon http://alternativeto.net/software/yed/, which has several programs which seem quite similar to what I want. I'll check them and see if I find the one. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion, I do like the fact Enthought software is open-source.